# phone screen is white and blank when debugging flutter app

Tags: flutter

When i launch my flutter app on debug mode with VS Code it gets stuck on a white screen forever after the apk is installed.
The app runs normal with the `flutter run` command.
I am using ubuntu linux system.

I have tried to launch debug mode using the command `flutter run --debug` , but it just runs like the normal flutter run command.

In addition, when using flutter run, it is not possible to hot reload or hot restart the app
...please i need your help!

Comment: Code, please ...